# MongoDB: Cloning single server dev. database to production shard cluster

Tags: mongodb, database

i was playing around on our dev server for a while for a new product and now it's sorta live and i want to move existing data from a single machine (mongod, local) to our 6 server shard setup (2 shards each a 3 replica set) - is there any way to clone the db to a remote shard?

(worst case, a simple dump & insert with shard key example would be very nice!)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your dev server to the sharding environement :

- Restart your dev server with the --shard option
- on your mongos : type db.runCommand( { addshard : "serverhostname[:port]", name : "migration" } );
- use the remove shard command to [remove](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/removeshard+command) your shard "migration".
- When it is done (you get "remove shard completed successfully"), you can stop your dev server and all your data have been migrated from dev to the new cluster

You don't have to shard your database for the migration, however you need to do it if you want to benefit from sharding.

The advantages of this solution is that you have **minimum action** to take ( everything is automatic) and there is **no downtime** (the more load you put, however, the slower the operation is)
However this is a **slow** solution (slower than a manual copy).

One more advantage compared to raw files copy  : the transfer will also compact (~ defrag) data, which is always good :-)

Comment: okay, so the addshard is the dev server - but how do i specify that the specific DB on the dev server is migrated over to the other shard? because as far as i thought sharding doesnt necessary mean its on all shard servers, if its a small amount of data it just stays within one shard == one box ... as in this case it might just stay on the shard which is the dev server now... or am i thinking wrong here?

Comment: @Tobias :as I said  add "dev" to the cluster and then use the command removeShard to make all data migrate from dev to the rest of the cluster. When the command removeshard returns "remove shard completed succesfully" all your data have been migrated

Answer (score 0):

- Add your dev server to a replica-set as the master, and the other 3 servers as slaves.
  Then remove the dev-server once the data was copied by the other servers.

  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Commands
- You can use `mongodump` to dump out the database, and then load the db-dump with `mongorestore` onto the master of each of your replica-sets

  `man mongodump` , `man mongorestore`

See:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Internals

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Master+Slave

Comment: would both of the solutions work with sharding? its not like i only have a replica set, its two replica sets both in a shard.

Comment: it's probably easiest to just load the data into the master, and then add the shards to that master